# Would I need separate author.p12, barsigner.csk, barsigner.db for BB10 app signing to the device?

Tags: blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

I have old BB signing files from last year. Would I need to update these for BB10? I can't get my app signed. I keep getting invalid password, but if I delete these, it asks for the author.p12 back. And I know my password. Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You have to ask for new keys: https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/

Comment: Never mind on that. I was able to build a new author.p12 that was associated with my signing privileges.